# Numpy: assign values to parts of dim 1 across all of dim 2

Tags: numpy

This works:

```
arr = np.zeros((4,3))
insert = 1
arr[2,:] = insert
```

If I want insert to be more than 1 value, it works when arr is 1d:

```
arr = np.zeros((4))
insert = np.ones(2)
arr[2:4] = insert
```

But what I want to do is apply insert to each 'row' of dim2. I can't get it work:

```
arr = np.zeros((4,3))
insert = np.ones(2)
arr[2:4, :] = insert
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (2,3)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Change your `insert` to 2D, so it can be broadcasted with your index. [`arr[2:4, :] = insert[:,None]`](https://uscript.co/public/annoym/python/d59d855c.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, whatever you are assigning must be the same shape of the array to be assigned

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((4,3))

insert = np.ones((2,3))

arr[2:4] = insert

print(arr)
```